# How to fix my price to show on "Pris:" in java in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```js
<script>
    // @ is an alias to /src

    export default {
        name: 'home',
        data() {
          return {
            inc: 0,
            inc2: 0,
            inc3: 0,
          }
        },

        methods: {
        toInc() {
          this.inc++
        },
        toDec() {
          this.inc--
        },
        toInc2() {
          this.inc2++
        },
        toDec2() {
          this.inc2--
        },
        toInc3() {
          this.inc3++
        },
        toDec3() {
          this.inc3--
        }
      }
      computed:{ //here i get this error with ";"
      total(){
      return this.inc+this.inc2+this.inc3;
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="plane">
        <div class="columns">
          <ul class="price">
            <div class="prisinfo">
              <p class="item">Ordinarie (<span class="cost">85kr</span>/st)</p> //those prices i need to get when im pressing on +
            <div class="priser">
            <li class="pris1"><a href="#" class="button" @click="toDec()">-</a></li>
            <p>{{inc}}</p>
            <li class="pris1"><a href="#" class="button" @click="toInc()">+</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prisinfo">
        <p class="item">Barn (<span class="cost">65kr</span>/st)</p> //those prices i need to get when im pressing on +
          <div class="priser">
            <li class="pris2"><a href="#" class="button" @click="toDec2()">-</a></li>
            <p>{{inc2}}</p>
            <li class="pris2"><a href="#" class="button" @click="toInc2()">+</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prisinfo">
          <p class="item">Pensionär (<span class="cost">75kr</span>/st) </p> //those prices i need to get when im pressing on +

          <div class="priser">
            <li class="pris3"><a href="#" class="button" @click="toDec3()">-</a></li>
            <p>{{inc3}}</p>
            <li class="pris3"><a href="#" class="button" @click="toInc3()">+</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <section id="totalprice">
        <p>Pris:<span class="total_price">{{total}}</span></p> // and here my total price after getting all the prices togheter after choosing how many tickets you need.
        </section>
```

I got error in console with "unexpected ;" and my dosnt work anymore after i did those changes. I need also to get the price to add when i press + and substact when i press -, i have the price in html.
You got my coments in the code if you need them.
Im so bad at vue right now, and java is my weak side too.

Comment: Just in case: you have a comma missing before "computed" in your code; is it possible this bug is just a typo?

Comment: Having just looked at the question edit history:  please don't make incremental changes to the question that invalidate current answers; it makes the site less useful for future users when the answers refer to parts of the question that no longer exist.

Comment: Yes it was comma (facepalm), thank you and sorry

Comment: No worries, it happens. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

to show the total price, you may find [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) very useful:
after your `data` property, add :

```
computed:{
   total(){
      return this.inc+this.inc2+this.inc3;
   }
},
```

and you HTML line would be:

```
<p>Pris:<span class="total_price">{{total}}</span></p>
```

now, about the + and - buttons:
they look good, i think its just a tiny mistake on the HTML side: you should call the function `toInc` with `()`.
like this:

```
<li class="pris3"><a href="#" class="button" @click="toInc3()">+</a></li>
```

(`@click` is like `v-on:click` https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand)

Comment: Please check again his code, his problem was about he didn't write a comma before the computed property. and other his codes is okay. Good luck.

Comment: @Ali Torki the question was edited after i published my answer, and if you take a quick look at the edit- the writer used my answer, and it is correct and useful. the missing comma problem came after that.